# "Real estate" or "property" in my particular case?

Tags: meaning-in-context, terminology, phrase-meaning

I am launching a service for adding and viewing classifieds of houses, land (plot) and commercial real estate. Must it be described as "Real Estate Listings Platform" or "Property Listings Platform"? Besides the description, in other areas of the website, I must use the term - when the *subject* is added, searched for, rated etc... Please help me, English is a foreign language for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real estate refers to a specific subset of property--land. Property can include things other than land, such as cars, companies and furniture. In the context of listings, both terms are usually used to mean real estate.

Comment: Oh thanks! May be "Real Property Listings Platform" ? :) I just want to be sure that if I use "property" only, it won't also mean it is a platform for cars, companies and furniture...

Comment: You could use either; people won't be confused. You asked for the difference in meaning so I explained it but, in your context, both are typically used to refer to land only.